# Forcing Gazebo to render at fixed intervals or how to record a video of a simulation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to be able to get a video of a Gazebo simulation. As far as I can tell, people are doing that by recording their desktop with things like RecordMyDesktop.
I don't find this to be very elegant, but more importantly my simulation runs very slow and I want the video to be real-time speed. The reason why the simulation is slow is that I have an external program communicating with a Gazebo plugin. The plugin's OnUpdate() blocks until communication with the external program completes.

To get around this, I wanted to save images from the simulation at every simulation step with the help of a system plugin as described in [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=system_plugin&cat=write_plugin) and then convert them into a video with ffmpeg/avconv.
However, I found that the video produced is very choppy. It looks like the plugin's call back function `event::Events::ConnectPreRender(boost::bind(&ImagePlugin::Update, this)));` is not actually called at fixed simulation time intervals. This appears to be true even when limiting the simulation by adding the following to the `.world` file, which effectively forces the real time factor to be 0.01:

```
<physics type="ode">
      <real_time_update_rate>10.00000</real_time_update_rate>
      <max_step_size>0.001000</max_step_size>
</physics>
```

This also not very satisfactory because with this, the simulation is running at a very conservative speed.

The next thing I tried was to run the simulation and record/log it, then filter the log to get a recording at a given update rate (with the -z argument) and playing that back with the system plugin that records the images:

```
# run the simulation headlessly and record it    
gzserver -r my_scara.world
# filter the log file at 30Hz
gz log -e -f ~/.gazebo/log/*/gzserver/state.log -z 30 --filter *.pose/*.pose > /tmp/filtered_state.log
# run the simulation from the recording and take pictures
gazebo -u -p /tmp/filtered_state.log -g image_plugin/build/libimage_plugin.so
```

This, however, runs the simulation very quickly and the plugins' Update() function is not executed 30 times per simulation-time second.

So my question is this: What can I do to get an image of the simulation at fixed intervals?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7116/forcing-gazebo-to-render-at-fixed-intervals-or-how-to-record-a-video-of-a-simulation/) by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 186 on 2014-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can insert a camera sensor that saves frames to disk. Attach this camera to a static model, such as a simple box, and you can then position the camera in space. Here is an example model that will store image frames in `/tmp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.5">
  <model name="camera">
    <link name="link">
      <pose>0.05 0.05 0.05 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <mass>0.1</mass>
      </inertial>
      <collision name="collision">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name="visual">
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.1 0.1 0.1</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        <camera>
          <horizontal_fov>1.047</horizontal_fov>
          <image>
            <width>640</width>
            <height>480</height>
          </image>
          <clip>
            <near>0.1</near>
            <far>100</far>
          </clip>
          <save enabled="true">
            <path>/tmp</path>
          </save>
        </camera>
        <always_on>1</always_on>
        <update_rate>30</update_rate>
        <visualize>true</visualize>
      </sensor>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on 2014-10-01**:
That's exactly what I need! Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-03**:
Is there a way to save a the most recent camera frame through either a console command or C++ program without having to enable ?

**Comment by [kpykc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/563/kpykc/) on 2014-10-07**:
I believe you can just copy rendered image to `OpenCV` image and save whole stream to video file (if you ok with using extrenal library with your code). Other way will be use `gazebo-ros-pkgs` and dump video/image from topic. Finally, you could publish rendered image using Gazebo topic and save with your client code.